# Copying an audio file with C, how do I store it?

Tags: c, file-io, wav

I am supposed to read an audio file -specifically wav- using C, produce some operations and then create a new file.

The problem is I am a bit confused with what I have to do.

1. I have to copy the first N bytes of the file with no modifications.

How do I store the first N bytes in a temporal variable? Should I use a type char*? I am reading it in binary mode.

2. How do I define the size of the file (how am I supposed to tell the program when to stop reading bytes because the file is X bytes big)?

I have not really worked with C before so I am a bit confused. Can someone write a small algorithm that copies a file byte per byte? This would be incredibly helpful since I could use that as a basis. I can't seem to find anything that does this on the internet.

Comment: Just plainly copying a file is *very* simple. You read X bytes into a temporary buffer, and write out the number of bytes that was read (remember that reading from a file may return less than requested number of bytes, for example if you hit the end of the file). Also read some C tutorials and books before trying to do anything, and experiment on smaller programs using arrays and pointers. You might also want [a good reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c) (IMO), especially about the [input/output system](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io).

Comment: Also note that unless you want to process the data you read in some way, a byte is a byte is a byte...

Comment: What type of pointer should I use to create the buffer, this is what confuses me.

Comment: If you're just reading bytes, note my previous comment, and learn about [the standard integer types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer). (I'd recommend looking at `uint8_t`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
unsigned char buffer[N];
```

for copying from and to file.

You can use

```
ftell
```

for finding file size.

May be below link will help you.
http://www.studytonight.com/c/file-input-output.php